# How can I dynamically create an dropdown menu list in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, list, unordered

Initially, I generated a `dropdown menu` by:

I have added more details about how I want to make a dropdown menu.

```
        <div class="well sidebar-nav">
            <img src="building.gif" style="display: block;margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;max-width:100%; max-height:100%;" />
            <div class="dropdown" style="padding-left: 20px; padding-top:5px;">
                <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" style="display: block;margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
                    Select A Building
                    <span class=" caret">
                    </span>
                </button>

                <ul id="myul" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1"></ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!--/span2-->
```

Now, I wrote the following code:

```
    var buildingList=[
          {
            "BuildingName": "Adler Journalism and Mass Communication Building",
            "BuildingNumber": "0456"
          },
          {
            "BuildingName": "Art Building",
            "BuildingNumber": "0021"
           } 
    ];

    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" style="display: block;margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
                        Select A Building
                        <span class=" caret">
                        </span>
                    </button>
    <ul id="myul" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    </ul>

     <script type="text/javascript">
      var out = "";
      var ul = document.getElementById("myul");
      for (i = 0; i < buildingList.length; i++) {
                out = ' <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href=" ' + buildingList[i].BuildingName + '  "> ' + buildingList[i].BuildingName + '   </a></li>';
                 var li = document.createElement("li");
                 var t = document.createTextNode(out);
                 li.appendChild(t);
                 ul.appendChild(li);
    }
    </script>
```

I would like to generate an `dropdown` list dynamically based on the `buildingList` array using `javascript`, can you help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The better idea is use select tag , and hardcode the select syntax as a string and add the child elements i mean the drodown options inside your for loop, create a div in html and finally you can innerHTML your code o the div

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```
$.each(buildingList, function (index, value) {
    $(".dropdown-menu").append($("<li>").text(value.BuildingName));
})
```

I created a fiddle so that you can see.

https://jsfiddle.net/bcub7wsL/1/

I changed the fiddle so that it just uses plain Javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/ha80r95b/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I think it is very valuable to me. While I think I should tell you more about how I would like to make my dropdown menu. I have modified my post and added more details about it . Could you please take a quick look and instruct me more? Thank you so much!!!

Comment: So I changed the fiddle slightly. I think this is more what you are looking for. Please up vote if this helps you.

Answer (score -1):

You can split the array and append the elements to drop down list.
I think this will help you.

https://css-tricks.com/dynamic-dropdowns/